# single cache for all subdomains

Tags: angularjs, caching, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a project developed in **Angular**. It has five modules and each have a sub-domain.

Example :

**drinks.example.com** *# lists all drinks of particular user*
**foods.example.com** *# lists all foods by a particular user*

I was able to set cookie for **.example.com** since there was an parameter option for setCookie.

but when i create a cache data, Browser creates separate cache for each of sub-domains. Is there any way we could tell the browser to use same cache for all sub-domains.

Comment: When you say browser creates cache, do you actually mean angular?

Comment: i mean when i write a code to create a cache in angular. the browser creates separate ones for each sub-domain.

Comment: You'll need to take a look at the https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory from angular. You simply create your cacheFactory. Inject it where your need it. Would have love to give you a plunker answer, but setting this take too much time and i don't have it. I'll give you this later if you need it.

Comment: i did that only..problem i that the cacheFactory is being created for each sub-domain. what i need is to create just one CacheFactory for **.example.com**

Comment: so it is not browser cache, it is angular cache